# Integral $\int_1^2 1/(x^2 \sqrt{x^2+1}) \, dx$

Tags: integration

What is $\int_1^2 1/(x^2 \sqrt{x^2+1}) \, dx$? Trigonometric substitution keeps getting too messy.

Comment: What substitutions have you tried?

Comment: x = tan(y) where -pi/2 < y < pi/2

Comment: @Albert And why didn't you succeed with that substitution?

Comment: That's the right one!

Comment: In this situation, the best thing to do might be to edit your question to show what you've done so far. You're probably making a mistake somewhere, and this way we can see what the mistake is.

Comment: I get to the integral from arctan(1) to arctan(1) of cos(y)/sin^2(y)dy and don't understand what to do next.

Comment: Write $u = \sin y$.

Comment: Are the bounds of the u = sin(y) substitution supposed to be sin(arctan(2)) to sin(arctan(1)).

Comment: Yes, but that simplifies.

Comment: @Albert Yes, those bounds are correct. Now draw two right triangles, one with sides $2, 1, \sqrt 5$ and the other with sides $1, 1, \sqrt 2$. Can you use this to simplify the terms?

Comment: Ah I see my mistake now, I was calculating the bounds to the integral wrong by subbing arctan(2) into u for some reason. Thanks everyone much appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040128/how-to-integrate-int-1-infty-fracdxx2-sqrtx2-1/1079665#1079665), with my answer included.

Comment: @Closevoters: If someone edits the content from the comments into the question, then there's clearly enough context given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let $x = \tan{\theta}$ so that $dx = \sec^{2}{\theta}\,d\theta$, with $0 < \arctan{1} < \theta < \arctan{2} < \pi/2$. Note that $\sec{\theta} > 0$ on this interval. Then we obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_{x=1}^{2} \frac{\sec^{2}{\theta}\,d\theta}{\tan^{2}{\theta}\sqrt{\tan^{2}{\theta} + 1}} & = \int_{x=1}^{2} \frac{\sec^{2}{\theta}\,d\theta}{\tan^{2}{\theta}\sqrt{\sec^{2}{\theta}}}\\
& =  \int_{x=1}^{2} \frac{\sec^{2}{\theta}\,d\theta}{\tan^{2}{\theta}\sec{\theta}}\\
& = \int_{x=1}^{2} \frac{\sec{\theta}\,d\theta}{\tan^{2}{\theta}}\\
& = \int_{x=1}^{2} \frac{\cos{\theta}}{\sin^{2}{\theta}}\,d\theta
\end{align*}

Now make the substitution $u = \sin{\theta}$ to get $\int_{x=1}^{2}\frac{du}{u^{2}} = \frac{-1}{u} \vert_{x=1}^{2}$. Going back to $x$ dependence, we have $u = \sin{\theta} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 1}}$. From here the answer is $\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{5}/2$.

Comment: Correct answer, but the OP was just about there on his own. Would have been better to let him post up his own answer, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Deepak: It is possible that as Mark was writing his answer, people were also working in comments. However, when I read the question, I did not see any of that, and would have answered similarly to Mark, if he hadn't. I see no reason to chastise here.

Comment: There's a sign error. Your final answer is negative.

Comment: I believe the answer here should be sqrt(2) - (sqrt(5)/2) not the one shown in the answer, but the steps are right.

Comment: The sign of $-\frac1u$ does seem to have been dropped.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the sign error.

Comment: @robjohn Wasn't intended to be chastisement just a suggestion for the future. But your point that people might already be working on an answer while others were commenting is a fair one.

Answer (score 1):

You can as well try a `hyperbolic` substitution: setting $x=\sinh t,\enspace t\ge 0$, you finally get for the indefinite integral: $$ \int\frac{\mathrm d\,t}{\sinh^2t}=-\coth t=-\frac{\cosh t}{\sinh t}=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}x, $$
whence $ \displaystyle\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm d\, x}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\sqrt2-\frac{\sqrt 5}2. $

Comment: Did you mean $x=\sinh(t)$?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it!